# how to autocast in sqlalchemy tinyint(1) to bool?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My app is creating sqlalchemy.Tables from a MySQL database and as it use tinyint(1) as boolean after select.select_from.all i am getting values with int instead of boolean. After that i am using json.dumps to pass it to a js receiver and that is the problem because js can't distinguish int from bool as they has the same type.
so my question is **how can i cast tinyint to bool in moment of execution .all() function in the simplest and most pythonic way?**

i have tables with columns which datatype is tinyint. when i am executing select().select_from().all() it returns values with ints, not with bools

Comment: update: if it is possible i would like not to use any raw sql queries

Comment: To clarify: you are attempting to query existing tables (not created by your app) that use tinyint?  Are you using the SQLAlchemy ORM or core?

Comment: You can't cast them during execute without raw SQL statement - MySQL always returns 0 (False) or 1 (True) since there is no native boolean datatype in MySQL.

Comment: snakecharmerb, i am querying existing mysql tables using sqlalcheny core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transparently convert the `TINYINT`s to booleans (and the reverse), there are a couple of approaches you could take, depending on how you are reflecting the tables.

Let's assume we have this table:

```
MariaDB [test]> describe t77148375;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c     | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If you are not reflecting, you can just define the table in the Python layer with the right type:

```py
tbl = sa.Table(
    't77148375', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True), sa.Column('c', sa.Boolean)
)
tbl.create(engine, checkfirst=True)  # Creates table in Python but not in the db.
```

If you are reflecting the tables via `autoload_with`, you can [override the column type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns) when you load the table.

```py
tbl = sa.Table('t77148375', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('c', sa.Boolean), autoload_with=engine)
```

If you are reflecting multiple tables at once, via `metadata.reflect`, you can use a [listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents.column_reflect) to automatically change the column type using the reflection process:

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(sa.Table, 'column_reflect')
def receive_column_reflect(inspector, table, column_info):
    # You may need to refine this test if you have TINYINT(1)s 
    # that aren't bools in the app layer.
    if isinstance(column_info['type'], mysql.TINYINT):
        if column_info['type'].display_width == 1:
            column_info['type'] = sa.Boolean


metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
```

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what i need